# Brackets match but Error: Reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java

```
public class IntList implements Cloneable 
{
    IntNode b = new IntNode();      // A reference to IntNode
    private IntNode head;           //Reference to first node of the linked list
    private IntNode tail;           //Reference to the last node of the linked list
    private IntNode currentIndex;   //Reference to node with current element
    private IntNode preIndex;       //Reference to node before the current element
    private int manyNodes;          //Number of nodes in the linked list
  // Student's invariant here
  public IntList() {        //Creates an empty linked list
      head = null;      
      tail = null;
      currentIndex = null;
      preIndex = null;
     manyNodes = 0;
    }   
}
```

This code is producing the error "error: reached end of file while parsing" and I'm not sure why since all of the curvy brackets match up

Comment: And what is `IntNode`?

Comment: It's a linked list, so it's probably just a class that holds a value and ref to next link @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Do you have other code in the same file? Comment out this class and see if you get the same "error: reached end of file while parsing" error. Edit: I can compile this class. You error is somewhere else in this file. This code is syntactically correct. Most likely there is missing punctuation somewhere above this code in your file (probably a `)` or `}`)

Comment: Compiles ok for me, after I place an empty `IntNode` class in its own file next to it.